# PrintDocument: Network printing takes 1-5 minutes (IIS)

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, printing, printdocument

I really need help with a problem I can not solve.

I am an automation project (Web Service) where some of the functionality is to print a text file (singular) server side.

This Web Service calls a .dll consisting of an object `PrintDocument` and after adding a few lines via `e.Graphics.DrawString` sends the content to the shared printer using the "PrinterName".

Everything works fine, except one small detail: When the Web service calls this .dll, it takes 1-3 minutes to print.

At the beginning I thought it might be my code, so I made a Windows Forms project using the same .dll and printing took only a few seconds.

I've tried everything, and I searched the internet and found nothing about it.

Please help me.

Thank you.
Hugs from Brazil

Comment: It is obviously your code. A WinForms app and a web app are completely different in running context, and printing from a web app is almost evil in all possible way with the part of code you shared. GDI+ was designed for WinForms scenarios and not for the web.

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: Typical approaches can be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-to-print or fully switch to electronic formats (such as PDF and so on) to get rid of the limitations of printing drivers (most such drivers do not work well with web apps).

Comment: For future readers, Microsoft explicitly states `System.Drawing.Printing` or `System.Printing` is not for ASP.NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing?view=netframework-4.8